# Finding location of download folder on Travis when using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, travis-ci

I've built some test which run on Travis-ci using Selenium + ChromeDriver.

I'm now trying to mimic a user downloading a file which is instantly downloaded to the `Download` directory, then use that same file to upload it into my application.

The issue I'm having is how to I determine the location of the `Download` directory from within my Travis-ci environment?

Comment: Have you tried setting it in the script? That way you should know where it is.

Comment: I don't know how I can determine the location of the `Download` directory when on Travis hence I'm asking. I've done plenty of research and the general answer is don't bother doing it or use `wget`. But thanks for your great advice on how to pose a question on SO!

Comment: Also I don't want to mimic a download with `wget`, I'm trying to get selenium to download the file then I'm trying to find the location it has downloaded to, to make sure the file was downloaded. But OS's are a big place and I don't know where it might be when in a Travis environment.

Answer (score 0):

Checking on Travis I didn't realise the environment is set on the `.yml` file and here are the environments that can be chosen https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/#Virtualization-environments

To locate the download and delete downloaded file I used `rimraf`
but I needed a script to check what OS was currently running (for people running tests locally) and a function to return the correct filepath given OS, here is the PureScript version:

```
fileLocation ∷ OperatingSystem → { user :: String, name :: String, ending :: String } → String
fileLocation operatingSystem {user, name, ending } = do
    case operatingSystem of
      Windows → "\\Users\\" <> user <> "\\Downloads\\" <> name <> ending
      Mac → "/Users/" <> user <> "/Downloads/" <> name <> ending
      _ → "home/" <> user <> "/Downloads/" <> name <> ending
```

if you are using JS it's just saying if OS is `Windows`, `Mac`, `_` then return following strings concatenated with values passed into the function of `user` (`process.env['USER']`), `name` of the file and the `ending` (.csv).